# ArrayList custom class as HashMap key

Tags: java, hashmap

I want to store my data in `HashMap<Point[], Double>`. I used iteration to assign the data, but when I checked at the end, the number of elements is only 1. I have implemented `hashCode()` and `equals()` in the custom class Point.

```
HashMap<Point[], Double> hmDistOrd = new HashMap<Point[], Double>();
Point[] keyPts = new Point[2];

for (int i=0; i<intersectionPts.size(); i++) {
p1 = intersectionPts.get(i);
    for (int j=0; j<intersectionPts.size(); j++) {
        p2 = intersectionPts.get(j);                
        if (!p1.equals(p2)) {
            keyPts[0] = p1;
            keyPts[1] = p2;
            d = p1.distance(p2);
            hmDistOrd.put(keyPts, d);
        }
    }
}
```

Any hints? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use array as a key, as array has default implementation of `hashCode` and `equals` from `Objects` and it doesn't consider it's elements.

To make it work you had to override `hashCode` and `equals` of array, but you can't do it.

You can use `ArrayList` instead, as it implements `hashCode` end `equals` comparing elements.

Comment: Use collection instead of array. It is easy. Change map to `Map<Collection<Point>, Double>` and use `Arrays.asList()` to fill it from array.

Comment: Oh, I just realized that I declared the key as Array. How silly. Let me edit it first and see if it works.

Answer (score 1):

You are storing the same array instance, keyPts, into the HashMap on every iteration (and overwriting its contents as well).

Answer (score 1):

As Jim said in his (deleted) answer, you are putting the same key object several times in the map, which will result in replacing the previous value.

But putting a new array for each element will not be better, either - then you will have more key-value-pairs, but you can't access them via the `get` method, if you don't have the right array object (and then you could have the value, too), as arrays do not implement `.equals` and `hashCode`.

To propose a solution: You could use an `List<Point>` as your key type, and use a new list for each pair of key points. Make sure you don't modify the list after putting it as a key into the map. (You can wrap it by Collections.unmodifiableList to make sure of this.)

An alternative would be some custom pair-of-points class (with it own hashCode and equals implementation).

Answer (score 0):

When you use an array as the key for a hash map it is that array's hashCode method that is used to determine the key's hash and not your Point class.

For your specific case I would try using a map of maps: `Map<Point, Map<Point, Double>>` or a custom 2D matrix class with 2 keys and a value.