# hashmap custom class key && object saving/loading

Tags: java, object, hashmap, serializable

Been working on a project for a while now and I've come across a few different complications and solutions that don't seem to pan out together.

```
final public class place implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8851896330953573877L;
    String world;
    Double X;
    Double Y;
    Double Z;
}
HashMap<place, Long> blockmap = new HashMap<place, Long>(); // does not work
HashMap<Location, Long> blockmap = new HashMap<Location, Long>(); //works
```

First, my hashmap is a hashmap containing the time an item was placed (or added) to the world. place is a 'class place {}' containing String world, double x, double y, double z; The problem i've had with this, is that it doesn't work with hashmaps. I can store a new hash key using it, but i cant call to get its value. Using Location instead fixes this problem (hashmap) and works flawlessly.

```
public void SetBlock(Block block) {
    Location loc = new Location(null, block.getLocation().getX(),block.getLocation().getY(),block.getLocation().getZ());
    //...
    Long time = (long) (System.currentTimeMillis() / 60000);
    //...
    if (blockmap.containsKey(loc)) {
            blockmap.remove(loc);
            blockmap.put(loc, time);
            //System.out.println("MyLeveler: Block Existed, Updated");
    } else {
            blockmap.put(loc, time);
            //System.out.println("MyLeveler: Block added to " + loc.getX() + ", " + loc.getY() + ", " + loc.getZ());
            //System.out.println("MyLeveler: total blocks saved: " + blockmap.size());
    }
}
```

This works without error. Now, for the purpose, this data has to be saved and reloaded when the plugin is disabled, and enabled. To do this, i created a new java class file with a save/load feature.

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;

public class SLAPI {
    public static void save(Object obj,String path) throws Exception
    {
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(path));
        oos.writeObject(obj);
        oos.flush();
        oos.close();
    }
    public static Object load(String path) throws Exception
    {
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(path));
        Object result = ois.readObject();
        ois.close();
        return result;
    }
}
```

I typically get "notserializable" errors. Using 'implements Serializable' and ois.defaultReadObject() or oos.defaultWriteObject() which checks the serial on the file results in a clean save/load only when the object is EMPTY! When it contains data, i constantly get "java.io.WriteAbortedException: writing aborted; java.io.NotSerializableException"

This is clearly a problem! One of the recommendations here: [ArrayList custom class as HashMap key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6775478/arraylist-custom-class-as-hashmap-key) failed to produce any better results. In fact, creating a custom class was my first issue to begin with >.>

So i guess the questions are:

1) What would i have to alter to use the custom class as a key (and work properly)

2) Why doesn't it recognize that i'm setting it as a serializable class/function/java class

3) Why does it work with an empty hashmap, but not with a filled hashmap?

Answer (score 4):

Basically you need to override `hashCode()` and `equals()` in `place`. Presumably `Location` already overrides these methods.

Those are the methods that `HashMap` uses to first narrow down the list of candidate keys very quickly (using the hash code) and then check them for equality (by calling equals).

It's not clear what the serializable problem is - my guess is that although `place` is serializable, `Location` isn't. If you could post a short but *complete* problem demonstrating the problem, that would really help. (It would also be a good idea to start following Java naming conventions, and making your fields private...)

EDIT: Here's an example of the `Place` class with hash code and equality. Note that I've made it immutable for the sake of avoiding the values changing after it's used as a key in a hash map - I don't know offhand how well that works with serialization, but hopefully it's okay:

```
public final class Place implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8851896330953573877L;

    private final String world;
    // Do you definitely want Double here rather than double?
    private final Double x;
    private final Double y;
    private final Double z;

    public Place(String world, Double x, Double y, Double z) {
        this.world = world;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.z = z;
    }

    @Override public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 17;
        hash = hash * 31 + (world == null ? 0 : world.hashCode());
        hash = hash * 31 + (x == null ? 0 : x.hashCode());
        hash = hash * 31 + (y == null ? 0 : y.hashCode());
        hash = hash * 31 + (z == null ? 0 : z.hashCode());
        return hash;
    }

    @Override public boolean equals(Object other) {
        if (!(other instanceof Place)) {
            return false;
        }
        Place p = (Place) other;
        // Consider using Guava's "Objects" class to make this simpler
        return equalsHelper(world, p.world) &&
               equalsHelper(x, p.x) &&
               equalsHelper(y, p.y) &&
               equalsHelper(z, p.z);
    }

    private static boolean equalsHelper(Object a, Object b) {
        if (a == b) {
            return true;
        }
        if (a == null || b == null) {
            return false;
        }
        return a.equals(b);
    }

    // TODO: Add getters?
}
```

It's worth noting that this will be comparing `Double` values for equality, which is almost always a bad idea... but you can't really give a tolerance in something like `equals`. So long as the values are *exactly* the same when you come to look them up, it should work fine.

Comment: the public/private cleanup would be done in a later stage when we plan to start using the code in a beta form. I'll see what i can do about creating a... smaller... project to display the exact complications as it fits in the code. - can you show me an example of the override process you were talking about? i've read up about it once or twice but wasn't sure how to use it?

Comment: @James: It's really a much better to get *simple* things like variable access right straight away. Will edit with an example of hashing for Place...

Comment: MANY thanks... very insightful. Been coding c++ so long, jumping into java has been a bit of a learning curve. The code you listed has a few flaws, like a null long would always == 0, making it not null, so i defaulted it to give the hashCode() to remove the error i was getting. Also, mistype "return equalsHeler(world, p.world) &&".  Think i get how serializable should be implemented now :P and the overrides will come in handy. My code now works without errors ^.^ guess i can clean it up now!! I was afraid i was going to have to save it to a SQL database for a second there >.>

Comment: @James: What do you mean by "a null long would always == 0"? There aren't any longs in there. But it's find for the hash to be 0. No single field can make the hash 0 though...

Comment: the 3 "hash = hash..." lines working on Doubles errors with "The operator == is undefined for the argument type(s) double, null", defaulted them to "hash = z.hashCode();" might be unsafe? If you know a better way, your welcome to lemme know

Comment: @James: Ah, that was probably just bracketing. See the edited version - I edited it for clarity, but it sounds like it was actually necessary.