# This is a very inelegant way of accomplishing what I want to accomplish. Curious what a better way is

Tags: java

It works and everything, but it looks horrible. All we're given to draw data from is a text file with the data on hockey players. We then take this data and create players from it. Then make a list of these players. At no point are we given each team's amount of wins, so I'm almost wondering if this *is* the best you can do.

Basically, what it wants to accomplish is to find the team with the most wins. This is found by the winning goals of each player being totalled, and judging by which team they were from, counting it for that team.

I accomplished this by creating the list of teams as Team objects by going through all the players and finding unique team names.

I then went through the player list and if the player's team was equal to the current team being looked at, it would give them points for the winning goals.

Then, in yet another for loop, find the team with the highest amount of these goals.

Return this team.

That's a total of four for loops for one little task. It seems gross.

```
    /**
     * Returns the team with the most wins
     */
    public Team getTeamWithMostWins() {
        Team teamWithMostWins = new Team();
        List<Team> teams = new List<Team>();

        if (!players.isEmpty()) {

            // Compile the List of teams
            for (int i = 0; i < players.size(); i++) {
                if (!teams.contains(players.get(i).getTeam())) {
                    teams.add(new Team(players.get(i).getTeam()));
                }
            }

            // Set the wins for the teams
            for (int i = 0; i < players.size(); i++) {
                String team = players.get(i).getTeam();
                int winningGoals = players.get(i).getWinningGoals();

                // Go through the teams List to set the points
                for (int j = 0; j < teams.size(); j++) {
                    // If the current player's team is equal to the current team in the loop
                    if ((teams.get(j).getName()).equals(team)) {
                        teams.get(j).incrementWinsBy(winningGoals);
                    }
                }
            }

            int mostWins = teams.get(0).getWins();

            // Find the team with the most wins
            for (int i = 1; i < teams.size(); i++) {
                if (teams.get(i).getWins() > mostWins) {
                    teamWithMostWins = teams.get(i);
                }
            }

        }
        else {
            teamWithMostWins = null;
        }

        return teamWithMostWins;
    }
```

Comment: Well for one, if you are just iterating over a collection, the for-each loop is usually a lot easier : ) http://www.leepoint.net/notes-java/flow/loops/foreach.html for an example

Comment: I don't think it looks bad. It's understandable, which far more important than looks or cleverness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Jordan Denison pointed out in the comments, you can used a for-each loop. See below for an example.

In addition, currently you will only get the last team which has more wins than the first team. In order to get the team with the most wins you have to update the most wins:

```
int mostWins = teams.get(0).getWins();

// Find the team with the most wins
for(Team team : teams) {
    if (team.getWins() > mostWins) {
        teamWithMostWins = team;
        mostWins = team.getWins(); // <--- Update the most wins every time you find a team with more wins
    }
}
```

### Update

In addition, consider using a map as shown in the other answers.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a Map to store how many wins each team has:

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;

/**
 * Returns the team with the most wins
 */
public Team getTeamWithMostWins() {
    if (players.isEmpty()) {
        return null;
    }

    Map<Team, Integer> teamWins = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

    // Set the wins for the teams
    for (Player player : players) {
        Integer count = teamWins.get(player.getTeam());
        count = (count == null)? 0 : count;
        teamWins.set(player.getTeam(), count + player.getWinningGoals());
    }

    Team teamWithMostWins = null;
    Integer mostWins = 0;

    for (Map.Entry<Team, Integer> teamWins : map.entrySet()) {
        Team team = entry.getKey();
        Integer wins = entry.getValue();
        if (wins > mostWins) {
            mostWins = wins;
            teamWithMostWins = team;
        }
    }

    return teamWithMostWins;
}
```

To do this you would have to add the hashCode() and equals() method to your Team class.

- [hashmap custom class key && object saving/loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7264373/hashmap-custom-class-key-object-saving-loading)

Answer (score 1):

```
int                  max      = 0;
Team                 mostWins = null;
Map< Team, Integer > counters = new HashMap<>();
for( Player player : players )
{
    Integer counter = counters.get( player.getTeam());
    if( counter == null ) counter = player.getWinningGoals();
    else                  counter = player.getWinningGoals() + counter
    counters.put( player.getTeam(), counter );
    if( counter > max )
    { 
        max      = counter;
        mostWins = player.getTeam();
    }
}
return mostWins;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could improve this code by breaking it down into smaller functions with meaningful names.

Aside from that, the fact that you are using Java ties your hands a bit. In languages with better support for higher-order functions, this kind of code could be written very, very concisely.

Because you asked for an example... here is a rough port of your code to Ruby:

```
teams = players.map(&:team).uniq
best_team = teams.max_by { |t| players.select { |p| p.team == t }.map(&:winning_goals).reduce(0,&:+) }
```

Comment: Could you give me an example of the last comment?

Comment: It's not really that complicated. The first line says: "Transform our list of Players into a list of their Teams. Then keep only one of each unique value. Assign that to `teams`." The second line says: "Find the team which maximizes the value of the following function: for a given team, run through the list of Players and keep only the ones that belong to that team. Transform the resulting list of Players into a list of their winning goals, then sum them up."

Comment: Transforming, filtering, and reducing lists are *very, very* powerful operations. Combine those with a terse syntax for anonymous functions, and you can do all kinds of things with very little code. If you look at your `for` loops, you'll see that generally you are doing those exact things: transforming a list, or filtering a list (perhaps both), or accumulating some kind of result from the members of a list. But you have to write all this repetitive code to manipulate indices.

Answer (score 0):

Using google guava:

```
final Multiset<Team> teamWins = HashMultiset.create();
for (Player player : players) {
  teamWins.add(player.getTeam(), player.getWinningGoals());
}

Team teamWithMostWins =
  Collections.max(teamWins, new Comparator<Team>() {
    public int compareTo(Team team1, Team team2) {
        return teamWins.count(team1) - teamWins.count(team2);
    }
  });

int mostWins = teamWins.count(teamWithMostWins);
```

Basically, the guava collection makes the counting part simpler for you.  Have not compiled this, but it should give you the right idea.  Just make sure that Team has a proper .hashCode and .equals methods (or you could assume that you won't duplicate team data in different object instances);